# Why D-link DNS 320 (NAS) cause files to get lost while moving between folders

Tags: nas

I own this NAS. I mapped the shares as Z:\ drive and begin moving my movies between folders.

But the new movie file size is 0Kb. The movie gone

```
TheLegend.Bluray.264.mkv - 0Kb 
---------------------------------------------------------------
TheLegend.Bluray.264.srt - 120Kb
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

What happened and can I restore my folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some programs like Teracopy don't support the NAS file system. If you transfer your files with  the windows explorer the copy will be ok.

Comment: OMG, is that true ? Yes I used Teracopy Free. I noticed it, thanks for the hint.

Comment: I had the same problem with Teracopy moving larger files from NAS to NAS. I contacted support and not response...